# connecting groups of duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have some data which has lots of duplication. For example, this data frame shows IDs in the data set that are known to be identical (e.g. row1 indicates a =b, therefore the rest of the data indicate that a=b=c and d=e=f):

```
a <- c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f')
b <- c('b','c','a','c','a','b','e','f','d','f','d','e')
duplicates <- cbind(a,b)
```

Is there any easy way to split these into two groups that are true IDs (e.g. here a,b & c are all the same and d,e & f are also all the same). So for my sample data:

```
a <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
b <- c('c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2')
new_id <- cbind(a,b)
```

The actual data has thousands of rows and is not fully connected (i.e. in a cluster of duplicates this could occur: a=b, a=c,b=/=c), due to some errors in duplicate detection.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how you're going from one example to the other and what you mean by a=b=c and d=e=f.

Comment: the first df gives pairs of IDs that are known to be the same and the second is my desired output whereby each ID gets grouped into a new ID (e.g. a=b=c=c1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking at network analyses. There are a few packages that deal with this. So you might want to use the one you are the most familiar with (network, tidygraph, igraph, diagrammeR). I use igraph, because I know that one a bit more than the others.

#### Steps:

First create a graph from the data using the dup data.frame. Next use the `clusters` function (or one of the other cluster options) to create clusters based on the data. Last step is to transform the clusters into a data.frame. Additionally you could plot the data (depends on how much data you have).

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dup, directed = FALSE)

clust <- clusters(g)

clusters <- data.frame(name = names(clust$membership), 
                       cluster = clust$membership,
                       row.names = NULL,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

clusters
  name cluster
1    a       1
2    b       1
3    c       1
4    d       2
5    e       2
6    f       2

# plot graph if needed
plot(g)
```

[image]

data:

```
a <- c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f')
b <- c('b','c','a','c','a','b','e','f','d','f','d','e')
dup <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work with factors.

```
df.1$id <- with(df.1, ifelse(as.numeric(a) %in% 1:3, "c1", "c2"))
new_id <- unique(df.1[, -2])
rownames(new_id) <- NULL  # just in case
```

***Yielding***

```
> new_id
   a id
1  a c1
2  b c1
3  c c1
4  d c2
5  e c2
6  f c2
```

***Data***

```
a <- c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f')
b <- c('b','c','a','c','a','b','e','f','d','f','d','e')

df.1 <- data.frame(a, b)
```

Comment: Does this scale up easily to the big dataset with probably many more different combinations OP indicated in his question? The `1:3` is a manually set range, this would probably be difficult for big and messy data.

Comment: @LAP I think so, because factors use less memory. Presuming the levels are really `a, b, c` as stated. Let's listen what OP says.

Comment: very nice code, but as @LAP points out this doesn't scale because in the real data I don't know what the groups are beforehand (that's what I'm trying to automate)